# I'm getting "product element contains unexpected child element RemoveFile error"

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have added one RemoveFile table entry inside product element like below:

```
<RemoveFile Filekey="xyz" Component_="acd" FileName="Def" DirProperty="avdf" 
 InstallMode="3">
```

Is there any reason why I'm getting above error?

Answer (score 0):

The [WiX reference](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/removefile.html) says the `RemoveFile` can only be a child of the tag `Component`. This is the reason of the error "unexpected child element RemoveFile".

Change your code to this:

```
<Component Id="Component_RemoveFile" Guid="{GUID}">
    <RemoveFile Filekey="xyz" Component_="acd"
                FileName="Def" DirProperty="avdf" InstallMode="3" />
</Component>
```